# How to replicate this gradient wave background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I came across the following design on Google:

[image]

I'd like to replicate it as accurately as I can (using different colors) in Photoshop/Illustrator. How would I go about doing this?

It looks like they not only have different layers of colors, but each layer also has its own gradient. And then it also looks like they may be apply a slight shadow between each layer?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I do not think there is a shadow between each layer, just a gradient fill.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! If you know how to draw with the [pen tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drawing-pen-curvature-or-pencil.html) and apply [gradients](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html) in Illustrator, that's basically it. No special trick to it.

Comment: @Scott I've made a gradient layer for each "wave", but I don't know how to smoothly cut between the layers to form these waves

Comment: @dfg1sdf8g1 what does "cut between the layers" mean? These are shapes layered on-top of eachother. Each wave is a unique object. Keith has an answer below that demonstrates this. The blue gradient is below the light teal wave in the layers panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty similar methods for illustrator and photoshop:

Select the pen tool (P) and make your shapes. If you are unfamiliar with how this tool works, check youtube to see it in action, that's the best way.

Give them a gradient fill. You can change the gradient colors and rotation to what you'd like. Here's a screenshot from photoshop. Notice I have the pen tool mode set to shape in the top left.

[image: gradient waves]